No inverse of $k^{-1}$ modulo $p-1$ in ElGamal signature scheme
In ElGamal's signature task, where such initial values ​​as the private key $x = 15$, session key $k = 10$, and hash of the message $h(M) = 15$ were given, it was told to calculate the public key $Y$ and create a signature for the message $(r,s) \pmod {p = 23}$, original root $g = 5$.
There were no problems with the calculation of the public key $Y$ and the constant $r$ according to the formula.
$$Y = g^{x} = 5^{15} =19 \pmod {23}$$
$$r=g^{k}modp=5^{10}=9 \pmod{23}$$
Difficulties arose when calculating $s$:
$$s=k^{-1}(h(M)-xr)=10^{-1}(5-15\times 9)\pmod{p-1=22}$$
The first step in calculating s should be calculating the inverse of $k^{-1}$ from the equation: $k^{-1}\pmod{p-1}$, which is equivalent to: $10x=1\pmod{22}$.
But there is no inverse of $k^{-1}$, since $\operatorname{GCD}(10,22)\not\equiv1$.
The correct answer is that it is not possible to create a signature? Will other input values ​​be chosen in real use of the algorithm?

Hello and welcome! I changed some parts of the formula so that it can be rendered prettier with the MathJax plugin on this site. As for the answer, I suppose in the real world the $k$ is simply re-selected, but your assignment may have other consideration.

@DannyNiu thank you for editing my comment.

So at the end of the day: either you select $k$ coprime to $p-1$ (per Daniel S's answer), or you select a "large" prime factor $n$ of $p-1$ and work modulo that $n$ rather than modulo $p-1$ (per DannyNiu's answer), including selecting $k\in[1,n)$. Notice that for security in actual use, $p$ must be large (at least 1280-bit or so), and $n$ (or a prime factor of $p-1$) must be large (at least 192-bit or so), otherwise it's easy to find the private key from the public key.

Per the wikipedia $k$ must be chosen coprime to $p-1$. Your choice of $k=10$ does not satisfy this requirement, and so it is not possible to compute the inverse.

Not exactly well-versed in Maths but:
There are 2 numbers: $p$ - the field which is 23 in your case, and $n$ the order of the generated group.
We can get a prime by performing a division: ${{p-1}\over 2} = 11$. and this will be our $n$ here, and 2 will be the "co-factor".
The letters $p$ and $n$ are from elliptic curve cryptography. I borrowed those terminology here, and they have equivalent in finite field cryptography.
